# How do I exclude files of a specific extension on druid ingestion spec?

Tags: amazon-s3, druid

I have these files on S3 URI: `s3://temp/sample/`

```
file_1.parquet
file_2.parquet
file_3.parquet
file_4.random
```

How can I exclude `file_4.random` in the ingestion spec JSON file?

What I know so far:
The spec file has options to include each file individually (uris) or the entire folder (prefixes), is there a way to include all files having the same extension?

```
"ioConfig": {
    "type": "index_parallel",
    "inputSource": {
      "type": "s3",
      "uris": null,
      "prefixes": [
        "s3://temp/sample/"
      ],
      "objects": null
    },
```

Comment: I thought that wildcards are supported in the prefixes uri, but I am not 100% sure. Did you test already with something like `"s3://temp/sample/*.parquet"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the filter property. In this example, I wanted to exclude those with  .log extension.

```
"ioConfig": {
  "type": "index_parallel",
  "inputSource": {
    "type": "s3",
    "uris": null,
    "prefixes": [
      "s3://temp/sample/"
    ],
    "objects": null,
    "filter": {
      "type": "not",
      "field": "filePath",
      "pattern": "\\.log$"
    }
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
"ioConfig": {
    "type": "index_parallel",
    "inputSource": {
      "type": "s3",
      "uris": [
              "s3://temp/sample/file_1.parquet",
              "s3://temp/sample/file_2.parquet",
              "s3://temp/sample/file_3.parquet",
      ],
      "objects": null
    },
```

Alternatively, just specify a wildcard in the URI:

```
...
      "uris": [
              "s3://temp/sample/*.parquet",
...
```

Comment: My question is how to "exclude" files of a specific extension, not "include"